# import two custom view libs, gravity repeat,namespace how to define in AndroidStudio without res-auto

Tags: android, android-studio

import two custom view libs in my project. but these libs both define attr gravity. so when i use res-auto to define namespace in AndoidStudio is not allow. how to define two namespace